# Does facebook support oEmbed?

Tags: facebook, oembed

Anyone know whether Facebook supports oEmbed for embedding videos (or other media) when a link is shared. I googled but cant get a definitive answer for this.

My question Facebook developer forum has no answer. http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=334549

Comment: hmmm.. there is no answer here too..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes** Facebook supports oembed. You can checkout the documentation here..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed-endpoints

**Note**: In order to make this API work properly **with ajax calls on mobile devices**; You need to use the endpoint domain "apps.facebook.com" instead of "www.facebook.com":

https://apps.facebook.com/plugins/post/oembed.json/?url={content-url}

This is because if you use the endpoint that is provided in the official documentation "www.facebook.com" the User agent of the mobile devices will force the redirect to "m.facebook.com" which does not have this endpoint implemented.

Answer (score 6):

Embedly is paid. Free alternative is [Noembed](https://noembed.com/). :)

Comment: they are a very interesting choices, but unfortunately, they don't support facebook as they claim

Comment: Yeah Noembed doesnt actually support Facebook, see https://noembed.com/providers ctrl-f facebook

Comment: Facebook does support oEmbed now.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no current support for oEmbed. You have two options (maybe more, but two that I know of):

1. Embedly http://embed.ly/
2. Engineer yourself an embedding solution for Facebook using the standard form of Facebook video embeds, eg:

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=VIDEOID&set=t.SOMENUMBER&type=2

becomes

`<object width="400" height="300" ><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/VIDEOID" /><embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/VIDEOID" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="300"></embed></object>`

Comment: It seems Facebook does support oEmbed now.

Answer (score 1):

The support is drastically changing in late 2020, to prevent anonymous access, and instead require a developer account and access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, but has few hiccups when implementing. I'd recommend you to try solution I wrote to overcome this: https://shobhitsharma.github.io/embedo